# DOMException thrown when calling the Web Crypto API

Tags: javascript, webcrypto-api

I've got the following code to generate a key using the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/deriveKey) in the browser:

```js
const IV = new Uint8Array([
  181, 205, 79, 202, 71, 30,
  192, 175, 44,  93, 57, 15,
  106, 207, 83, 179
]);

const SALT = "I'm so salty!";

async function generateKey(password, crypto) {
  const enc = new TextEncoder();
  const keyMaterial = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw",
    enc.encode(password),
    "PBKDF2",
    false,
    ["deriveBits", "deriveKey"],
  );

  return await crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
    {
      name: "PBKDF2",
      salt: SALT,
      iterations: 100000,
      hash: "SHA-256",
    },
    keyMaterial,
    { "name": "AES-GCM", "length": 256},
    true,
    ["encrypt", "decrypt"],
  );
}
```

When called like this:

```js
await generateKey("some password", window.crypto)
```

the `deriveKey` function throws an exception `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: An invalid or illegal string was specified` with no further details provided. What am I doing wrong? Btw, I'm on latest Firefox Developer edition.

Note that when called in NodeJS as

```js
import { webcrypto } from "crypto";
await generateKey("some password", webcrypto)
```

it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the docs for the [PBKDF2 algorithm config](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pbkdf2Params), the SALT must be an ArrayBuffer, a TypedArray, or a DataView. You are passing a string. I believe you can use the existing text encoder you already have (though I have not tested this):

```js
salt: enc.encode(SALT),
```

Note: the code from your question throws a different-yet-more-helpful error in Chrome.